# Lack of Memory of Geometric Distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to prove by induction that if f is a PMF and P has a lack of memory property, then P is a geometric distribution and $$f(k) = p (1-p)^k \hspace{1cm} \forall k, m \geq 0$$ What I have done so far is I set $$P(X = m+k | X \geq m) = f(k)$$, and I set m=1 to prove by induction on k, and then I let $m>0$ and showed the case for general $m$. But I'm not sure if I can just prove by induction the case $m=1$ and then generalize it to all $m$, leaving all $k$.

Comment: I don't think it has. It is just an excuse to allow measures required for conducting some experiment.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of formal proof you're looking for.  For brevity, let $q = 1-p$. Then $P(X = m+k | X \ge m) = \frac{P(X = m+k, X \ge m)}{P(X \ge m)}= \frac{q^{m+k-1}p}{q^m} = q^{k-1}p = P(X=k),$ and you're done.